# Format decimal to string in correct culture info

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

What is the best way to format a decimal amount to string for UI display in the correct culture info?

Comment: What's wrong with `myDecimal.ToString()`?

Comment: Loading nHibernate object from database, property is decimal and when call toString() it does format with correct decimal places.

However when saving setting the same property from text eg.

allocation.Price = Decimal.Parse(price, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

but once this is set and call allocation.Price.toString() decimal places not added.

eg after decimal parse 15 want 15.00 but toString just gives 15.

Strange?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a format to the ToString: `myDecimal.ToString("#.00")` or `myDecimal.ToString("C")`.

For a nullable decimal (`decimal?`) you will need to use the .Value property (`myNullableDecimal.Value.ToString("C")`) or cast the value to a plain (non-nullable) decimal. Be sure not to do this when the value is `null` or you will get an exception!

See the documentation for [Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) or [Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) numeric format strings.

Comment: nHibernate property was Decimal? therefoer the format option was not available on toString method. Now creating decimal variable and using your answer and works a treat. cheers!

Comment: if it's a Nullable<decimal> then you could either user the .Value property or cast to decimal (if you are sure it's not null)

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @WeaponX - fixed. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 8):

Why not `decimalVar.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`. For format strings (the "F2" part) and what they do, see  [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you want to use a culture specified by the user you can use:

```
string userInfo = "en-US";

yourDecimal.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(userInfo));
```

or

```
yourDecimal.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo(userInfo));
```

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

Comment: so what? He is not asking for dynamic cultureInfo.

Comment: JavaScript is not 'Global' aware, so I used .ToString("#.00", New CultureInfo("en-GB", False))