# I'm getting rounding that I don't want when formatting a number in c#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

As I understand from Microsoft's documentation, if I have 340550.46 and I apply the format string #,##0.00 I should get the string "340,550.46".  But instead, I'm getting "340.550,50".  I've set breakpoints to ensure that I know what the number and format strings are going in.

To be more specific, I have a string "340550.46", and I convert it to a float, and then use ToString() to format it with "#,##0.00":

```
float.Parse("340550.46").ToString("#,##0.00)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Why is it rounding the number, and what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: Is your question about the [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688396/11683) or the [decimal comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23156197/11683)?

Comment: `float` or `Single` are limited to 7 signfiicant digits, which would be 345550.5.  Change the type to `double` for up to 16 significant digits.

Comment: The final output is subject to your Locale settings. There's an overload that allows you to specify the locale you wish. Not sure whether a duplicate because not sure yet what you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341677/format-decimal-to-string-in-correct-culture-info

Comment: @RickDavin: Two digits after the decimal place could well be money, in which case `decimal` is more appropriate.

Comment: @RickDavin, can you put that as an answer and I'll mark it right?  Also, I'm an idiot.

Comment: For future questions please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - the current code in the question unnecessarily combines two steps into a single line making it harder for everyone (and you in particular) to understand the issue. Separating paring and formatting would let you see what specific step causes problem you don't understand. I.e. "why `340550f +.46f` is 340550.5" could be a way to ask about part you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the rounding is that a `float` is limited to 7 signficant digits.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

If you changed to a `double`, you would get that 8th extra digit.  Also, if you are formatting to 2 decimal places since it may be currency, consider using `Decimal`.